# List all unique directories that contain string1 that contain files that contain string2

Tags: bash, shell, find

Say I want to find all directories that contain a certain string (say `a` here) that also contain files that contain a certain other string (say that are `.txt` files). What are the different ways of doing this? One way is to do a command substitution, such as:

```
mkdir dira; mkdir dirb
touch dira/file1.txt; touch dira/file2.doc; touch dirb/file3.doc
find `find . -type d -iname '*a'` -type f -iname '*.doc'
```

However, this does not work if I am trying to find hidden directories that contain this file:

```
find `find . -type d -iname '.*'` -type f -iname '*.doc'
```

In this case, it just prints to stdout the inside find. How does one do this? The more ways to do this, the more instructive. A shell script would also be instructive.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Setup test directories
mkdir dira dirb .dirc .dird .hiddena

# Setup test files
touch dira/filea1.doc dira/filea2.doc dira/filea3.txt
touch dirb/fileb1.doc dirb/fileb2.doc dirb/fileb3.txt
touch .dirc/filec1.doc .dirc/filec2.doc .dirc/filec3.txt
touch .dird/filed1.doc .dird/filed2.doc .dird/filed3.txt
touch .hiddena/filehiddena1.doc .hiddena/filehiddena2.doc .hiddena/filehiddena3.txt

find . -type d -name "*a" -print | while read DIR 
do
    find $DIR -type f -name "*a*.doc" -print
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./t.bash 
./dira/filea1.doc
./dira/filea2.doc
./.hiddena/filehiddena2.doc
./.hiddena/filehiddena1.doc
```

My first version used a for loop but that can cause issues if you have spaces in your directory names, thus the `while read` loop.

---

From your comment, I did this:

```
# Setup test directories
mkdir dira dirb .dirc .dird .hiddena

# Setup test files
touch dira/filea1.doc dira/filea2.doc dira/filea3.txt
touch dirb/fileb1.doc dirb/fileb2.doc dirb/fileb3.txt
touch .dirc/filec1.doc .dirc/filec2.doc .dirc/filec3.txt
touch .dird/filed1.doc .dird/filed2.doc .dird/filed3.txt
touch .hiddena/filehiddena1.doc .hiddena/filehiddena2.doc .hiddena/filehiddena3.txt
touch .hiddena/z

find . -type d -name "*a" -print | while read DIR 
do
    #find $DIR -type f -name "*a*.doc" -print
    find $DIR -type f -name z -print
done
```

The output I get is:

```
$ ./t.bash 
./.hiddena/z
```

So I do not understand why you get double z.

Comment: Thanks! The piping into the while read works. However, if I change one of the files to , say, *z* and then look for that one, the output is the correct file, but shown twice, even though only one file exists. Also, why does the command substitution not work ? Or, alternatively, using find . -type f -path "*/.*" -iname ".doc" if looking for hidden directories with .doc files?

Comment: Thanks again and to User Unknown. Yes,I think the reason it produces a double output is that without a -mindepth 1 option in the first find, it picks up as well the current directory ./ and searches that (again) , thereby producing the double output.

Comment: How would I add to the script or the command line so it only prints out once per path ? Say there are a couple of files called z there, and I don't want to print out multiple times if the directory is the same.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the actual directory being evaluated (as ./ or ../pwd/), just use:

```
find .* -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.doc'
.dira/file11.doc
.dira/file10.doc
.dira/file9.doc
.dirb/file11.doc
.dirb/file10.doc
.dirb/file9.doc
```

After using

```
touch .dir{a..b}/file{9..11}.doc
```

with the longer pattern .dir* it is more easy:

```
find .dir* -type f -iname '*.doc'
.dira/file11.doc
.dira/file10.doc
.dira/file9.doc
.dirb/file11.doc
.dirb/file10.doc
.dirb/file9.doc
```

Command substitution works too (don't use the outdated backticks, please)

```
find $(find . -mindepth 1 -type d -iname ".*") -type f -iname '*.doc'
./.dirb/file11.doc
./.dirb/file10.doc
./.dirb/file9.doc
./.dira/file11.doc
./.dira/file10.doc
./.dira/file9.doc
```

Comment: @user166624: If you suggest an edit you should test, if it works. I tested your `improvement` but it didn't work.

Comment: You mean adding the " " around the $() to avoid having an error thrown if the directory name contains spaces? This worked for me and solved the aforementioned error I was getting when I tried it with names containing spaces. What didn't work for you and which shell are you using ?

Comment: Your command yields `find: './.dirb\n./.dira': No such file or directory` where the subdirectories are named "dira, dirb, .dira, .dirb". I'm using bash, and the non working command is the one, where you made an edit. If you think you have a superior solution which is different, post your own answer.

Comment: Hi user unknown. You re right - for you examples of .dira and .dirb it does produce that error. My apologies of only testing it against my example which had spaces in the directory name. So, for example, if I mkdir ".dir c" ; touch .dir\ c/file{1..4}.doc and then repeat your command, then I get the error on the *c directory. Any idea why my suggestion - "$(find . -mindepth 1 -type d -iname '.*')" - doesn't work in this case?